# Knapsnack algorithm detecting objects

Tags: c++, algorithm, knapsack-problem

There is a simple dp solution of this problem:

```
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

int knapsack2(const std::vector<int>& wts, const std::vector<int>& cost, int W)
{
    size_t n = wts.size();
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > dp(W + 1, std::vector<int>(n+1, 0));
    for (size_t j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        for (int w = 1; w <= W; w++) {
           if (wts[j-1] <= w) {
               dp[w][j] = std::max(dp[w][j - 1], dp[w - wts[j-1]][j - 1] + cost[j-1]);
           }
           else {
                dp[w][j] = dp[w][j - 1];
           }
        }
    }
    return dp[W][n];
}
```

But how can I know what objects were taken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the second vector "prev" with the same dimensions as dp.

When you choose the best option for dp[w][j], write coordinates of previous cell to prev[w][j]

When the job of dp is done, walk from prev[W][n] back to get all the used cell indexes

Comment: It's only necessary to save one coordinate - wi, the second we always know - i-1. And while we are going on prev we need to compare D[I][J] and D[I-1][J], if they are equal we didn't take J object?

Comment: Yes, only one coordinate is necessary. No, we shouldn't compare dp[][], just check change of coordinate (if w changes, we use this item). Comparing dp - another method (without prev)

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your approach is the lack of encoding the concept of an item as an entity. You should create a type "item" (using the `class` or `struct` keyword) to describe an item with weight, cost and some sort of identifier (name or number) as members. That way you only need to send a single vector of items, and any solution will be a list of such items, which answers your question.

**Edit**

Per request, here follows a more practical explanation of how to naively get this working.

Create a type, `item` which contains all info of a single item. Take an `std::vector<item>` as input to replace both `wts` and `cost` Then, the smallest possible change is to change `dp` so that it stores pairs consisting of a running cost and an item list. This would give it the type `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int,std::vector<item>>>>`. That is, for every stored (partial) solution, keep track of its cost and the items giving this solution.

This type for `dp` looks rather hideous, but if you get it working, you can improve the implementation later. For example, you can store pointers to `item`s, to avoid copying. Also, a few `typedef`s could really help clarify the definition of `dp`.. The important thing is to first get it working with the simplest solution, then think of those improvements.

Comment: I don't understand how to change the algorithm to have a list of items as a result

Comment: @NikeStrike I've added a bit more detailed explanation of how to achieve this. Please let me know if I need to clarify further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map and once the object is made ​​you will be able to make a query using the map. An optimization algorithm will be achieved by using a HashMap.